# Illustrator Batch EPS to JPEG Conversion

Tags: scripting, applescript, batch-processing, adobe-illustrator, eps

I am looking for a way to use Illustrator's "Export As..." functionality on Mac for multiple files at once. I have tried the actions but can never get them to work, and they don't seem to simply do what I want them to.

If anyone knows an AppleScript for this that would be great.
I need to convert multiple .eps files into RGB color model, maximum quality .jpegs

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the comments [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1332439/illustrator-automate-ai-files-export-with-batch)

Comment: Thank you, I finally figured out how to record and use a batch action on Illustrator CC. It works beautifully!